# Finding errors in the triangle area

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, area

The lengths of sides b and c of a triangle ABC are measured accurately, while angle A is measured with an error of 1/2 degree.

If b = 12cm, c = 15cm and angle A is 30 degrees, what is the approximate value of the error in the area of this triangle?

Our teacher wanted us to think about this in the lesson. I used the $\frac12 b c \sin (A)$ formula but couldn't find it. Do you have any comments?

Comment: now expand $\sin (A+x)$ wrt $x$

Comment: we cant use calculator on exam. so ı cant calculate sin(0.5) or ...

Comment: you can cosider $\sin(0.5^{\circ})$ approx. equal to the angle, i.e to $0.5^{\circ} $ but expressed in radians

Comment: Details like no use of calculator, a given set of answer options (multiple-choice test), etc. should be explained in the body of the question, not in comments. If you really were given this as a multiple choice question you should also list the answer options.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your idea is right and we can use that

$$\Delta S= \frac12 b c \sin (A+\Delta A)-\frac12 b c \sin (A)$$

with

$$\sin (A+\Delta A)=\sin (A)\cos (\Delta A)+\sin (\Delta A)\cos (A)$$

---

As an alternative we can use that

$$\frac{dS}{dA} =\frac12 bc \cos A \implies \Delta S \approx \frac12 bc \cos A \Delta A$$

with

$$\frac{\Delta A}{\Delta A°}= \frac{\pi}{180}$$

Comment: But how do we calculate the 0.5 degree in the exam?. I think there must be another way.

Comment: @MonthyPr Can't you use the calculator?

Comment: Perhaps you are supposed to use the fact that $sin(\Delta A)\approx\Delta A$ for small $\Delta A$ (if $\Delta A$ is in radians...)?

Comment: There is no $pi/180$ in the answer options.

Comment: @MonthyPr To use the second way we need to convert degrees in radians that is about  1/120.

Comment: Since $\pi \approx 3$, $pi/180 \approx 1/60$. Since all of the problem is about approximation on different parts, this seems acceptable. If it is a multiple choice problem, you can check if the answer you get is given. If not, try to find which one is nearest to yours. Since people can approximate differently, my guess is that the wrong answers will be off by a factor of at least 2 in either direction.